# How can I generate system-wide unique IDs under Linux

Tags: linux, unique

I'm working on a multiprocess Linux system and need to generate unique IDs. Security is not a consideration, so an ID generator that starts at zero and counts up would be fine. Also it's just within a local machine, no network involved. Obviously it's not hard to implement this, but I was just wondering if there was anything already provided (preferably lightweight).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This sounds like a job for... ...[**`uuidgen`**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uuidgen):

```
% uuidgen 
975DA04B-9A5A-4816-8780-C051E37D1414
```

If you want to build it into your own application or service, you'll need [`libuuid`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libuuid):

```
#include <uuid/uuid.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    uuid_t uu;
    uuid_generate(uu);
    char uuid[37];
    uuid_unparse(uu, uuid);
    std::cout << uuid << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there anything that can be invoked within a process, rather than having to fire up a new one just to return the id?

Answer (score 1):

There is a command line tool called uuid that will do exactly what you want. I'm not sure if it gets installed by default in various distributions though, so you may have to do that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In cases where **uuidgen** is not installed you can use **mktemp**. For example, for 16 characters (should be enough to achieve system-wide unique IDs) ...

> mktemp -u XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Answer (score 0):

Also useful..

```
 cat /etc/machine-id
```

The /etc/machine-id file contains the unique machine ID of the local system that is set during installation. The machine ID is a single newline-terminated, hexadecimal, 32-character, lowercase machine ID string. When decoded from hexadecimal, this corresponds with a 16-byte/128-bit string.

Comment: I checked a Debian system that was at hand and **could not** find that file.

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't have that file