# How to get timestamp exact enough to differ every time it's fetched?

Tags: c++, performance, timestamp, guid, cpu-cycles

To generate global unique ids, I need something like a timestamp of their creation. But those ids can be generate directly after each other in source code. So the time with milliseconds isn't accurate enough and could unintentionally produce equal ids.

Thefore I need a timestamp exact enough that it differs every time it is fetched. I though about CPU cycles, but I don't know if there is a way to get this information.

Since this is for a realtime game, fetching the timestamp is performance related. Moreover, it is cross-plattform compatible to Linux, Windows and Mac, so of course the timestamp should be, too. If there is no standard way, I could live with three distinctive solutions for the systems.

Comment: Most platforms have a family of functions for creating and manipulating UUIDs in one form or another. Are the not sufficient for your needs ? (I.e. why reinvent that wheel, its a road not well-taken). Is there a specific target platform you had in mind?

Comment: What do you mean by platforms?

Comment: Is this for Linux? Windows? Etc... Or are you looking for a general solution that is platform independent ? For example, 128bit UUIDs are easily creditable on Linux using libuuid and `uuid_create()` [(example)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606733/how-can-i-generate-system-wide-unique-ids-under-linux). On Windows, [`UuidCreate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379205(v=vs.85).aspx) is one way to do it, etc. Not saying you need to go down either road. Just a suggestion depending on what the *real* problem is you're trying to solve. Maybe save you some time.

Comment: My application is cross platform compatible supporting Windows, Linux and Mac. Using a library would be fine. In my case, I have to name or data related to the id, so I thought about using a combination of perfectly exact timestamp and MAC network address would be save. Since this is for a realtime game, this is performance related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timestamps are not very good for this, unless you are guaranteed to have a high resolution time-source. Some systems have this, others don't.

In particular, if the system has multiple CPU's, the "timestamp counter" for each CPU may not be in sync, so you may get duplicates simply because the number of clockcycles on one CPU is "behind" the number of clockcycles on another CPU.

In a POSIX system, you may be able to use a [`clock_gettime`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) which does have a nanosecond resolution, and should be fairly fast too.

I wrote this code to test it out:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    timespec ts[100];

    for(auto &t : ts)
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t);
    timespec old_ts = {0};
    for(auto &t : ts)
    {
    long diff = 0;
    if (old_ts.tv_sec)
    {
        diff = t.tv_nsec - old_ts.tv_nsec;
    }
        cout << "ts.nsec: " << t.tv_nsec << " diff=" << diff << endl;
    old_ts = t;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**

Of course, the absolutely simplest form of a unique ID is a 64-bit atomic counter - it is the fastest, and it's simple. Assuming you have C++11 features:

```
#include <atomic>

typdef long long int id_type;
std::atomic<id_type> current_id;

id_type get_next_id()
{
   return current_id.fetch_add(1);
}
```

Not sure if visual studio has atomic, but you could use [`InterlockedINcrement64()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms683615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
InterlockedIncrement64(&current);
```

Comment: Could modern CPU cores perform the task twice per nanosecond? I cannot sense how short a nanosecond is. Moreover my application is cross plattform and I need to support Linux, Windows and Mac.

Comment: You won't be able to get into a system call and back out again in 1 ns on two different CPU's. And for Windows at the least, you'll have to find a different solution.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer. I just asked because otherwise the same id would be generated because, of course, the network address doesn't change. That would not even crash my application but would cause undesired behavior, which might not even be noticed at first.

Comment: @danijar: I have just added another method. It won't work across a network or some such, but if you combine that with for example a "per-system" ID (such as IP address), it should work well.

Comment: The application will run multiple times. Ids create before might, or might not be loaded into the system then. So I don't always have access to the lastest created id.

Comment: So, use a named shared memory region and do your atomic increments on that.

Comment: I think one of us misunderstood the other one. The application may be used to create an id, on exit that gets stored to disk. The file containing the id could be loaded at any time on any machine later on. How could a simple counter guarantee uniqueness?

Comment: Ah, ok. Then use the create uid type functions that are available for Linux and Windows, as suggested by WhozCraig.

Comment: Could I use the C++11 `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` for cross platform support, or isn't it exact enough?

Comment: Yes, it should have cross-platform support. However, I don't know that it's guaranteed to be precise enough - after all the C++ standard does not say much about how high a resolution timer you need in the system... You may find that it's still 1 or 16ms in a Windows machine...

Comment: Okay, and couldn't I store the last time an id was created and a counter variable to append another digit to the time? Hope you understand what my idea is.

Comment: Of course you could, but then you could also store a 64-bit number and just increment it, if you are going to store something.

Comment: Better idea that I came up with today is to use network address, time and a random number. Then it won't matter that much if the time isn't exact enough.

Comment: That would also work, as long as the random number doesn't repeat itself (so don't seed it with `time(0)`